# Почему разбивая строку методом split строку появляется элемент с пустой строкой?

Tags: javascript

```
[ 'RRRR\nPPP\n', 'OOO\nKKK\n' ]
```

Это массив со строками, после разбивки его на меньшие сроки -

```
console.log(result[i].split('\n'));
```

в возвращеном массиве появляется элемент с пустой строкой -

```
[ 'RRRR', 'PPP', '' ]
```

Почему так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут все довольно просто, сплит как бы разрезает строку по \n и пустая строка именно то что нужно ожидать. Попробуйте убрать последний \n символ.